# AMP-list (Autosuggest) error 'no-cors'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amp-html, amp-list

I am using **AMP-Autosuggest** while I using this the error occurs. I Don't know how can I solve this.

The API And web are in different domain.

**Error:**

```
No '**Access-Control-Allow-Origin**' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to '**no-cors**' to fetch the resource with **CORS** disabled.
```

Code:

```
<div class="suggest">
  <div
    class="autosuggest-container hidden"
    [class]="(showDropdown && query) ?
      'autosuggest-container' :
      'autosuggest-container hidden'"
  >
    <amp-list
      class="autosuggest-box"
      layout="fixed-height"
      height="120"
      src="https://myapi.com/data.json?q=xxx"
      id="autosuggest-list">
      <template type="amp-mustache">
        <amp-selector
          id="autosuggest-selector"
          keyboard-select-mode="focus"
          layout="container"
          on="
            select:
              AMP.setState({
                query: event.targetOption,
                showDropdown: false
              }),
              autosuggest-list.hide"
        >
          {{#results}}
            <div
              class="select-option no-outline"
              role="option"
              tabindex="0"
              on="tap:autosuggest-list.hide"
              option="{{.}}"
            >{{.}}</div>
          {{/results}}
          {{^results}}
            <div class="select-option {{#query}}empty{{/query}}">
              {{#query}}Sorry! We don't ship to your city {{/query}}
            </div>
          {{/results}}
        </amp-selector>
      </template>
    </amp-list>
  </div>
</div>


<amp-state id="autosuggest">
    <script type="application/json">
    {
      "endpoint": "https://myapi.com/data.json?q=xxx",
      "emptyAndInitialTemplateJson": [{
        []
      }]
    }
    </script>
  </amp-state>
```

Comment: What exactly is unclear? Are you aware how CORS works? If not, go read up on it.

Comment: Ya, but how can I specify on request

Comment: No clue what you mean.

Comment: no I mean to say cors it handles by server-side or I can specify on request if on request so how can I do this because there is no proper procedure given by AMP

Comment: if you know please tell me

Comment: Why are you saying that you are aware how CORS works then - when that is clearly not the case? No, you can of course _not_ specify it from the client side. _“because there is no proper procedure given by AMP”_ - this is absolutely not specific to AMP.

Comment: i know what is a cross-origin, but there anyway without using changing on the server to implement

Comment: and on localhost it give same error

Comment: both my rails serve are running on localhost but different port. but it give same error.

Comment: Different port = different origin. // The server you are sending the request _to_ needs to allow this, by responding with the right headers.

Comment: so, on localhost how can I do this.

Comment: You configure your server to respond with the necessary headers … Whether the package/libraries/whatever you are using also provide a way to do this via configuration, or whether you have to somehow issue these headers manually - for you to find out, check the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem with small changes done to my API server.

In My rails Serve I use **rack-cors gem**

In **Config/application.rb**

```
  config.middleware.insert_before 0, "Rack::Cors" do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get, :post, :options]
      end
    end
```

Allow CORS

```
response.headers['AMP-Redirect-To'] = request.protocol+request.host_with_port+url
response.headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'AMP-Redirect-To, AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin'
response.headers['AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin'] = params[:__amp_source_origin]
```